# Initializing ApplicationContext in Servlet

Tags: spring, servlets, applicationcontext

I am building an application with Spring, Hibernate, JSP and Servlets. For each form action method i am passing the values to Servlet and i am declaring ApplicationContext to load spring.xml in all the servlets.. Is there any way i can delcare ApplicationContext at one place in servlet and get all beans there...

I declare

```
 ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
 Student student = (Student) ac.getBean("student");
```

I declare this in all servlets..is there any central place to declare this and get beans in servlet..

Comment: Normally in a Spring APplication there is only the Spring DispatcherServlet. The actual Code handling the http requests is in (spring managed) controllern. Into these you inject the dependencies. You should rethink your design. What you want to do is not "spring-like". [Have a look into the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let Spring autowire your beans wherever you need them. This is the preferred way of doing things. If you are not familiar with the `@Autowired` annotation in spring, just do this-

1. Add this to your something-servlet.xml

   ```
   <context:component-scan base-package="you_base_package" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   ```

   your_base_package is the base package which contains your Student
   class and other classes which you want to autowire(or instantiate).
2. Annotate your Student class and others with `@Component`.
3. Use this to get an instance of Student and others wherever needed.
       `@Autowired Student student;`